# Signed URL in Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, azure-cdn

I can create Authentication using the following cookies with CloudFront,

```
Set-Cookie: Domain=example.org; Path=/images/*; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Expires=1426500000
Set-Cookie: Domain=example.org; Path=/images/*; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Signature=yXrSIgyQoeE4FBI4eMKF6ho~CA8_
Set-Cookie: Domain=example.org; Path=/images/*; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=APKA9ONS7QCOWEXAMPLE
```

which takes care of Authentication.
With Custom Authorizer policy shown below it can take care of Authorization.

```
{
  "principalId": "user",
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789012:ymy8tbxw7b/*/GET/"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can make I similar configuration with Azure?

Answer (score 0):

you can look this

Azure CDN Verizon 
Securing Azure CDN assets with token authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth

Using Azure CDN with SAS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-sas-storage-support

restrict with this as well Using Azure CDN with CORS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors

with Azure CDN Verizon you can block Country, IPs, Your network...
Azure CDN rules engine reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine-reference

NICE: Verizon-specific HTTP headers for Azure CDN rules engine
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-http-headers

Override HTTP behavior using the Azure CDN rules engine
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine

Azure CDNs powerful new Premium Features
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-cdns-powerful-new-premium-features/